# Webview back button is killing all activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

i know that may duplicate some threads but i can#t figure out what i wrong. I have slider dreawer where are fragments and in fragments there are webview. Everything is working fine at least one thing, namely when i press back button it closes the app. I have tried some other possible solutions but anything is not working. I even don't get any errors. I even tried this easy solution but without any progress

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

[My Main activity:](http://pastie.org/9613761)

[And this is one of my fragments:](http://pastie.org/9613768)

Comment: It appears that you are using a MainActivity and then multiple fragments inside (slidingdrawer) or otherwise. Let me know If this understanding is correct.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right.

Comment: Please see the answer below and accept if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

By default back button shall close the app, if you are at the main/landing activity(there are other ways as well). If you want to override backbutton behavior, you should be overriding onBackPressed(), which you are doing right, but you should avoid calling super.onBackPressed() (since this gives you the default behavious, i.e. closing the activity OR finish(), with this you're closing the activity yourself. which is what you want to avoid.

Hope it helps.

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mSlidingDrawer.isOpened()) {
        mSlidingDrawer.close()
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MyTestApplication.getAppContext(), "Closing application", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: I really don't know if i do it wrong but still nothing. One way close button is not doing anything and other way it closes application.

Comment: You'd need to add your logic to handle back button press. I updated the example.

Comment: I think i have to let it be because it's not working. Maybe you can try it in your code? Maybe my emulator is faulty?